# MAMP Pro - Host database missing

Tags: mamp-pro

I fired up MAMP Pro this morning and one of my databases is missing.

It's not listed in the Databases list within Mamp Pro and it's not listed within phpMyAdmin either.

I did a few things recently (listed below) that may have contributed to this but 
**my Question 1 is**

1. Are databases stored as individual .sql files anywhere within my Mac? I don't see anything in **/Users/me/Library/Application Support/appsolute** that is obviously a sql file. If I knew where to locate this, I could try recover a .sql file with a file recovery software

Things I did that may have caused this
1. I upgraded from Mamp Pro 5.0.1 to 5.0.3 this morning
2. As part of that upgrade I had to run a Tools > Upgrade database

APart from that I can't think what might have happened. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MAMP PRO has information here on missing databases.

https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215198946-I-upgraded-to-MAMP-PRO-5-and-I-am-missing-databases-

Your MAMP PRO 4 database most likely did not get copied over.